# How to be an OpenID consumer?

Tags: openid

Does anybody know or have any documents which I can use to build a site that consume OpenID? For example when user come to my site I accept an OpenID, then I will redirect them to OpenID provider, then when they are authenticated then they will be redirected back.

I just want to know is there any steps or standard URLs to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question for Google, really. [Here](http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe) is a plausible-looking explanation on how to implement OpenID support on an existing website.

Answer (score 1):

[Open-id Selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/)
and if .net
[DotNetOpenID](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/)

Answer (score 1):

[rpxnow.com](http://rpxnow.com) will give a quick way to accept openid's via a SaaS service.